# Map of Specific US States? (Isolated)

Tags: graphics, curated-data, geography

My question here is fairly basic, and I'm sure I'm overlooking something basic. I know about `CountryData` for creating shapes of entire countries, and it works, to an extent; I can plot geographical data on it with the coordinates, but I'd like to have a magnified view of a state alone. The goal is to be able to measure borderlines. Is there built-in functionality for this, or do I have to import a shape file of a state?

Comment: Related: [Mathematica North America map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8957067/mathematica-north-america-map).

Comment: You'll need shape files.  Another similar question is [this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14327/7167)

Answer (score 14):

There is no built in option, however for the US it's very easy because the coordinates of the state borderlines are all over the Internet. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814169/geographical-boundaries-of-states-provinces-google-maps-polygon) led me to one such [data set](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/states.xml). I'll include how I cleaned it up, like this:

```
data = Import["http://econym.org.uk/gmap/states.xml"];
name[{"name" -> n_, ___}] := n
coordinates[XMLElement["point", {"lat" -> lat_, "lng" -> lng_}, {}]] := {lat, lng}
states = 
  {name@Part[#, 1], coordinates /@ Part[#, 2]} & /@ 
    Partition[Cases[data, XMLElement["state", state__] :> state, Infinity], 2];
```

However there is no point in redoing those things over and over. You might as well define `states` like [this](http://pastebin.com/KFJRAGaN) (the link leads to Pastebin where the list of coordinates is available. The list is too large to post here.)

To draw a specific state you can do something like this:

```
state[name_] := states /. {___, {name, pts_}, ___} :> (ToExpression /@ pts)

ImageReflect[ImageRotate[Graphics[{
    RGBColor[0.896, 0.8878, 0.8548], EdgeForm[GrayLevel[0]], 
    Polygon[state["Indiana"]],
    PointSize[Medium], Red,
    Point[CityData[{"Clinton", "Indiana", "United States"}, "Coordinates"]],
    Point[CityData[{"Indianapolis", "Indiana", "United States"}, "Coordinates"]]
    }], Pi/2], Right]
```

[image: Indiana]

Of course you will be able to design better utility functions than I have to stuff away operations such as `ImageReflect` and `ImageRotate`.

Just another example to show how this can be used to draw the US map in it's entirety. You could very easily style each state individually.

```
ImageReflect[ImageRotate[Graphics[{
    RGBColor[0.896, 0.8878, 0.8548], EdgeForm[GrayLevel[0]], 
    Polygon[state[First@#] & /@ (
       states /. {
         {"Hawaii", __} -> Sequence[],
         {"Alaska", __} -> Sequence[]
         }
       )],
    PointSize[Medium], Red,
    Point[CityData[{"Clinton", "Indiana", "United States"}, "Coordinates"]],
    Point[CityData[{"Indianapolis", "Indiana", "United States"}, "Coordinates"]]
    }], Pi/2], Right]
```

[image]

(I know your purpose is not visualization, but someone will surely come along sooner or later looking for how to do visualization.)

**Update**

As of *Mathematica* 10 we don't have to find data sources ourselves.

```
indiana = GeoGraphics[{
   GeoStyling["OutlineMap"],
   Polygon[
    Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Indiana", "UnitedStates"}]]},
  GeoBackground -> None,
  Frame -> True,
  FrameTicks -> None
  ]
```

[image: Indiana]

To extract the polygon coordinates we may do this:

```
pts = Cases[indiana, Polygon[data_] :> data, Infinity];
(* To plot the polygon: Graphics[Polygon[First@pts]] *)
```

Or we can get the polygon like this:

```
EntityValue[Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Indiana", "UnitedStates"}], "Polygon"]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I had already worked out a similar approach before your answer, in part from the comments above, but this has helped streamline it a bit. Just as a side question, is there any way to make your two points above different sizes in the same `Graphics` function?

Comment: @SmithW. Yes, you can easily change the settings in between graphics primitives, for example `{Red, PointSize[Small], Point[{0,0,0}], Green, PointSize[Large], Point[{1,0,0}]}` creates two different points with different colors and sizes. Look up `PointsSize` to see how you can specify different sizes.

Comment: Technically, both `GeoGraphics` and `Entity` use wolfram-alpha, so they're dependent on external data sources.

Comment: @rcollyer Thanks, I changed my wording.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned this is dead easy now with `Entity`:

```
GeoGraphics[
 With[{h = RandomReal[.9], s = RandomReal@{.4, .8}, 
      b = RandomReal@{.4, .6}},
     {
      EdgeForm@Hue[h, s, b + .2], Hue[h, s + .2, b - .2], Polygon@#}
     ] & /@ (EntityList[
      EntityClass["AdministrativeDivision", "AllUSStatesPlusDC"]] // 
     DeleteCases[#, 
       Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"DistrictOfColumbia" | 
          "Alaska" | "Hawaii", "UnitedStates"}]] &) // 
  RandomSample[#, 15] &
 ]
```

[image]

And with all the `Geo*` functionality we can get things like perimeters trivially:

```
In[90]:= Map[(#[[2, 1]] -> 
     QuantityMagnitude@
      GeoDistance@
       Apply[Join]@First@First@EntityValue[#, "Polygon"]) &, 
  EntityList@
   EntityClass["AdministrativeDivision", 
    "AllUSStatesPlusDC"]]~RandomSample~15

Out[90]= {"NorthCarolina" -> 3500.57, "Connecticut" -> 682.115, 
 "Tennessee" -> 1278.5, "SouthDakota" -> 1265.04, "Hawaii" -> 1440.61,
  "Delaware" -> 502.202, "Florida" -> 6264.55, "Iowa" -> 1089.67, 
 "Alaska" -> 58774.3, "Oklahoma" -> 1565.76, "Missouri" -> 1428.25, 
 "Arkansas" -> 1286.78, "Texas" -> 4460.52, "WestVirginia" -> 1136.57,
  "NewHampshire" -> 529.748}
```

Comment: +1, but I would not call it "dead easy"...