# SatelliteData for a hypothetical satellite

Tags: curated-data, astronomy

`SatelliteData` appears to have some sort of orbit propagator behind it. It works for existing satellites, but is there any way to use it to predict the orbit of a hypothetical satellite that might be launched in the future?

Comment: I think you're into one of those areas where the documentation isn't terrifically helpful.  I suspect that this question and answer - https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/102948/how-can-i-define-geographic-regions-and-new-entities - might get you started.  Do report back on your adventures.

Comment: @JohnDoty Curious if you figured out to do this?

Comment: @Cassini Never did.

Comment: @JohnDoty Thank you for the reply.