# How to create a Text with certain size given in a specified way?

Tags: graphics, output-formatting, formatting

[image: img]

**Note**: all these coordinates are in `Graphics` system, not text size system. so specifying simply by `Style[text, 5]` or so won't work......

I have some text and I would like to show them in some order in `Graphics`, but I want them to be in certain size so it will looks good. (Primarily for improving my answer to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96121/how-to-recreate-a-certain-word-cloud/119174#119174) problem).

So, I can give the left top point's coordination and the length(in the first case) or the width(in the second) of the text.

How can I create a text just in this size? Surely `Text[Style["Text Text",size],pos]` won't work in this way.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. :)

---

## Edit 1

Provide some data for experiment:

Text:`"56个7"`

Position data, given in {Position,size} pairs, when `size`'s first part is larger that the second, it's parallel, and when not, horizontal:

```
{{{342, 135}, {189, 500}}, {{756, 590}, {232, 71}}, {{404, 707}, {232,
    71}}, {{954, 541}, {232, 71}}, {{381, 653}, {232, 71}}, {{1280, 
   457}, {76, 23}}, {{1155, 506}, {172, 53}}, {{607, 631}, {232, 
   71}}, {{357, 762}, {232, 71}}, {{623, 700}, {172, 53}}, {{988, 
   613}, {117, 36}}, {{502, 242}, {76, 23}}, {{1170, 440}, {117, 
   36}}, {{1121, 464}, {172, 53}}, {{992, 499}, {172, 53}}, {{337, 
   621}, {58, 160}}, {{865, 655}, {117, 36}}, {{335, 314}, {172, 
   53}}, {{800, 562}, {172, 53}}, {{474, 127}, {58, 160}}, {{523, 
   130}, {58, 160}}, {{1251, 419}, {117, 36}}, {{1195, 546}, {117, 
   36}}, {{377, 613}, {117, 36}}, {{354, 221}, {117, 36}}, {{753, 
   693}, {117, 36}}, {{630, 739}, {117, 36}}, {{383, 515}, {117, 
   36}}, {{383, 816}, {117, 36}}, {{923, 529}, {76, 23}}, {{406, 
   393}, {76, 23}}, {{681, 614}, {76, 23}}, {{359, 132}, {76, 
   23}}, {{1316, 486}, {76, 23}}, {{429, 498}, {76, 23}}, {{414, 
   464}, {76, 23}}, {{600, 773}, {76, 23}}, {{416, 372}, {76, 
   23}}, {{357, 363}, {38, 11}}, {{523, 192}, {76, 23}}, {{1175, 
   581}, {76, 23}}, {{350, 455}, {31, 80}}, {{427, 551}, {76, 
   23}}, {{1097, 604}, {76, 23}}, {{976, 649}, {76, 23}}, {{336, 
   232}, {31, 80}}, {{836, 689}, {76, 23}}, {{873, 547}, {76, 
   23}}, {{380, 644}, {76, 23}}, {{373, 748}, {38, 11}}, {{337, 
   132}, {31, 80}}, {{425, 447}, {76, 23}}, {{418, 483}, {76, 
   23}}, {{416, 407}, {76, 23}}, {{1180, 529}, {76, 23}}, {{611, 
   689}, {76, 23}}, {{1088, 485}, {38, 11}}, {{976, 566}, {31, 
   80}}, {{1146, 487}, {76, 23}}, {{341, 549}, {31, 80}}, {{832, 
   670}, {76, 23}}, {{412, 126}, {76, 23}}, {{1319, 492}, {31, 80}}}
```

---

## Edit 2

Check my answer, now my only concern is that how to make White region totally transparent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert text to `FilledCurve` graphics primitives by converting via PDF. See [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8287) for example.

In the example below I get the bounding box of the resulting graphics using `PlotRange`, then use `Scale` and `Translate` to size and position the text as required.

```
t = Style["Text Text", FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 60];

g = ImportString[ExportString[t, "PDF"]][[1, 1]];

{{a, b}, {c, d}} = PlotRange @ Graphics[g, PlotRange -> All, PlotRangePadding -> None]
(* {{1.29598, 168.789}, {9.56801, 38.5115}} *)

Graphics[
 Translate[Scale[g, 5/(b - a), {a, d}], {2, 3} - {a, d}],
 PlotRange -> All, PlotRangePadding -> None, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: this is quite helpful when generating high quality output!

Answer (score 5):

You can convert your `Text` to `Graphics` and then use any size

```
 Show[ImageCrop@Graphics@Text@Style["Text Text", 80, Bold, FontFamily -> Times],
      ImageSize -> 200]
```

[image]

You can change the font size to get a better resolution. With a little modification you can use it inside a canvas in the way you want.

```
insert[txt_String, col_, pos_List, angle_, size_] := Module[{text},
text = ColorReplace[ImageCrop@Graphics@Text@Style[txt, col, 80, Bold,
FontFamily -> Times], White];
Inset[text, pos, {0,0}, size, {Cos[angle], Sin[angle]}]]

Graphics[{
insert["Text Text", Red, {100, 100}, 0, 300],
insert["Text Text", Blue, {300, 100}, Pi/2, 200],
insert["Text Text", Green, {100, 100}, Pi/4, 300]},
PlotRange -> {{0, 400}, {0, 400}}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image]

With proper control over size and position. `pos` is the coordinate of your bottom left corner of the text.

Comment: This is a good start, but how can I position them? I can only give out the coordination of the left top point.

Comment: edited, are there any idea to position those characters and format both position, angle, and textsize?

Comment: @Wjx Could you clarify what you are asking? It seems to me that Sumit's answer already provides control of position, angle, and text size.

Comment: @MarcoB er, I suppose this answer cannot provide a control for position? check the link in my question, I'm trying to draw a word cloud like that, I've already got the position of the text and their size, just cannot show them elegantly.

Comment: @Wjx, I hope the modified answer would be useful. Previous answer did not work because I used `ImageCrop` to eliminate the extra white space.

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I didn't express what I want to do clearly. I can see this one can do some positioning and resizing stuff, but as I've said in my question, I can only specify the left up corner's coordination, but I can see that in your answer, you specify the center of the text. Also, you used Style to specify the size of the text, but That's a not a size in Graphics's coordination system. So I f I want the text, for example 000, 's upper side to  extend from {0,0} to {0,1} in x axis, how can I do this? thanks! I will update my post to state this more clearly.

Comment: I think I've got some idea from your answer~Let me try

Comment: @Wjx I think I get your point now. Check the new answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, Your answer is great but @simon woods' answer is wider applicable and can be more easily scaled in what ever form I want. So I accepted his answer. Your answer is surely helpful!

Answer (score 1):

First, I'll have to admit that those data should be modified a bit:

```
wd2="56个7";
dat={{#1[[1]], -#1[[2]]}, #2} & @@@ Map[Reverse, **Those data**, {2}];
```

Then, just following @Sumit's answer, we'll have to use `Inset` to do this job, but we need to further specify the alignment by using `Inset`'s Third options. Then, we also need to use the size option(the fourth option) in `Inset` to make the graphics in our desired form.

In this way, we can easily rule out the actual form of the code:

```
Graphics[Inset[
    Rasterize[
     Style[wd2, ColorData["BlueGreenYellow"]@RandomReal[], Bold, 
      FontFamily -> Times], RasterSize -> 1000], #1, {Left, Top}, #2, 
    If[#2[[1]] > #2[[2]], {1, 0}, {0, 1}]] & @@@ dat, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1000}, {-2000, 0}}, ImageSize -> 800]
```

Though the result is still not satisfying, I think I'll post this first in hope that someone may further improve this code.

---

## Edit 1

The alignment and size needs a bit more formatting while the text is rotated as these options will only specify the points before rotation:

```
Graphics[Inset[
    Rasterize[
     Style[wd2, ColorData["BlueGreenYellow"]@RandomReal[], Bold], 
     RasterSize -> 1000], #1, 
    If[#2[[1]] > #2[[2]], {Left, Top}, {Right, Top}], Reverse@Sort@#2,
     If[#2[[1]] > #2[[2]], {1, 0}, {0, 1}]] & @@@ dat, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1000}, {-2000, 0}}, ImageSize -> 800]
```

This time the result will be quite pleasing, and the only thing left is about opacity. Thanks for everyone!!!

[image: result]

Comment: "the only thing left is about opacity" - try `ColorReplace[]`.